# In ASP.Core, what does "injecting IStartup directly into the dependency injection container rather than calling UseStartup or Configure" mean?

Tags: asp.net, .net, dependency-injection, asp.net-core

In the [ms docs Hosting in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/hosting?tabs=aspnetcore2x#troubleshooting-systemargumentexception) the last section states:

> **If the host is built by injecting `IStartup` directly into the
>   dependency injection container** rather than calling `UseStartup` or
>   `Configure`, the following error may occur:
>
> `Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: A valid non-empty application name must be provided.`
>
> This occurs because the `applicationName(ApplicationKey)` (the current
>   assembly) is required to scan for `HostingStartupAttributes`. If the app
>   manually injects `IStartup` into the dependency injection container, add
>   the following call to `WebHostBuilder` with the assembly name specified:

```
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseSetting("applicationName", "<Assembly Name>")
    ...
```

I can't figure out what is meant by the bold first line above. How would you directly inject the `IStartup` into *the dependency injection container*? Does it mean passing a startup instance into a constructor somewhere (not likely)? The documentation points to [an example](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/8377d226f1e6e1a97dabdb6769a845eeccc829ed/samples/SampleStartups/StartupInjection.cs) for further information where both normal and injected startups are added using `UseStartup<>` injection syntax. The only difference I see is that the injected is called by an `Ihostingstartup` implementation but the "necessary" `UseSetting()` wasn't called in either of the two. What does the bold sentence above mean?

Answer (score 1):

> How would you directly inject the IStartup into the dependency
>   injection container?

You can do this by

```
IWebHostBuilder webbuilder = new WebHostBuilder().ConfigureServices(services =>
{
    services.AddSingleton<IStartup>(mockStartup);

}).UseSetting(WebHostDefaults.ApplicationKey, "<ApplicationAssemblyName>");
```

> Does it mean passing a startup instance into a constructor somewhere
>   (not likely)?

It means registering your own instance of the `Startup` class.

If you are looking into mocking up the `Startup` class and use your own (mocked) instances for the dependencies for the controllers, whereby the controllers will use your mocked dependencies while your integration unit test runs then you would more likely to build the host by injecting the `Startup` class directly into the  injection container.

Suppose you have to test that your controller returns appropriate HTTP status codes while it also validates the input parameters using Asp.net core filters, you would like to write something like this in your unit test method:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await httpclient.PostAsync($"/api/{controllerName}", jsonContent);
```

then in the assert area you could do...

```
Assert.That(response.StatusCode, Is.EqualTo(HttpStatusCode.Created));
```

The controller action looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateJobDetailsRequest]
public async Task<IActionResult> AddNewJobRequest([FromBody] AddNewRequest addNewlRequest)
{
    Entity detailEntity = this._mapper.Map<AddNewRequest , Entity>(addNewlRequest);

    await this._manager.AddRequest(detailEntity);
    this._logger.LogInformation($"The detail = {jobDetailRequest} has successfully been dispatched.");
    return Created(string.Empty, addNewlRequest);
}
```

If you would test this method directly then you are not testing the `ValidateJobDetailsRequest` which checks if the model is valid and returns bad request (HTTP 400) status if model is invalid.

You can ask any question in the comments if I have missed anything.